# SQLDeveloper 4.0 not showing connection for SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have downloaded the latest version of SQL Developer (4.0.2.15) and am trying to add capability to connect to a SQLServer database too.

I have followed instructions over the internet and added the SQLServer JDBC jar in the "Third Party JDBC drivers", however, still not able to see any new connection capability for SQLServer (still shows only connect to Oracle and Access only).

Please guide if there is any extra step required or if doing anything wrong?

*Screenshots attached below:*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting your SQL Developer after installing the jdbc?

Comment: @Charlesliam Yes, a few times already. No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need jtds-1.2-dist.zip with jtds-1.2-dist.jar in it

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thank you.  Although, not sure why the other sqljdbc.jar does not work !